# How can I create a single ActionListener for multiple JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm creating a basic calculator using MVC. So far I'm adapting a tutorial which merely sums two user entered values together.

Currently each button I'm adding to the view has it's own listener, which is ok. However, the controller as per the tutorial has a single ActionListener inner class per button. This repeats a huge amount of code.

How can I create a single ActionListener class for all buttons pressed, and use a case statement on the id of the button pressed?

**Registering the oneButton in the View**

```
void oneListener(ActionListener listenForOneButton){    
    oneButton.addActionListener(listenForOneButton);
}
```

**Implementing the ActionListener for the oneButton in the Controller inner class**

```
class oneListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int previousNumber, displayNumber = 0;          
        try{
            previousNumber = theView.getPreviousDisplayNumber();
            displayNumber = previousNumber+1;               
            theView.setDisplayNumber(displayNumber);
        }           
        catch(NumberFormatException ex){                
            System.out.println(ex);             
            theView.displayErrorMessage("You Need to Enter Integers");              
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SingleActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void initializeButtons() {
        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[4];
        String[] buttonNames = new String[] {"button1", "button2", "button3", "button4"};

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(buttonNames[i]);
        }
    }

    public void addActionListenersToButtons() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformedd(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (actionEvent.getSource() == buttons[0]) {
            //Do required tasks.
        }

        if (actionEvent.getSource() == buttons[1]) {
            //Do required tasks.
        }

        if (actionEvent.getSource() == buttons[2]) {
            //Do required tasks.
        }

        if (actionEvent.getSource() == buttons[3]) {
            //Do required tasks.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with class which implements `ActionListener`...

```
public class CalculatorHandler implements ActionListener{

    public static final String ADD_ACTION_COMMAND = "Action.add";

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if (ADD_ACTION_COMMAND.equals(e.getActionCommand()) {
            // Do your addition...
        } else if ...

    }
}
```

It's best to define the action commands that this class can handle is constants, thus removing any ambiguity...

Next, in the class that holds the buttons, create an instance of the `ActionListener`...

```
CalculatorHandler handler = new CalculatorHandler();
```

Then create you buttons as per usual and register the `handler`...

```
JButton plus = new JButton("+");
plus.setActionCommand(CalculatorHandler.ADD_ACTION_COMMAND);
plus.addActionListener(handler);
```

The only problem with this approach, IMHO, is that it can create a monster `if-else` statement which may become difficult to maintain.

To my mind, I'd create some kind of model/builder that contained a series of helper methods (like `add(Number)`, `subtract(Number)` etc) and use [Actions API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for the individual actions for each button...but that's just me...

Comment: +1 for `Action`; see `DefaultEditorKit` and `StyledEditorKit` as examples.