# Java Set multiple JButtons to one MouseListener

Tags: java, jbutton, mouselistener

I'm programming a quiz game in Java. I'd like to know whether if it is possible to set multiple JButtons to one MouseListener to make things easier for me. 
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you may use use single listener for one or more Buttons. For more information read tutorial [pages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html)..

[Here Is a example for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007807/how-can-i-create-a-single-actionlistener-for-multiple-jbuttons)

Comment: Thanks for your help:) This has really saved me from ten hours of putting mouse listeners on every single button:)

Comment: If your problem have been solved then accept the answer so other don't visit your solved question. And Keep Smiling.. :)