# Apply common code to group of jbuttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is it possible to apply a common code to multiple `jbuttons` in a frame on click of any `jbutton`.
Its like when I click, say `jbutton80`, then:

from `jbutton1` to `jbutton75`

{

`// common code that applies to all jbutton in loop`

}

I am making quiz app in java and have around 70-80 buttons in `jframe`. Each button corresponds to a question. Questions are divided in sections.
So I want:

//if user selects(or clicks on `jbutton`) section a `setvisible(true)` from `jbutton1` to `jbutton20` and setvisible(false) from `jbutton21` to `jbutton 80`.

Sorry, if this question has been asked before. I tried to search any relevant post but couldn't find one.

Comment: Embrace the Action interface.  [See SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007807/how-can-i-create-a-single-actionlistener-for-multiple-jbuttons)

Comment: Thanks, your link did the job. All I need is to edit a little base code that netbeans created automatically for me. Sorry, I am unable to +1 your comment. I'm newbie to this forum and has to figure out how to do this.... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try making an action listener

```
ActionListener l = new ActionListener() { /* code here */ };
```

And then adding the same one to all of the JButtons?

```
for (JButton b : buttons) {
     b.addActionListener(l);
}
```